# Unify 2 bytes to Int

Tags: c++

I have a function that allows me to separate a INT value in 2 Bytes
(e.g: INT "123123" results in E0F3; `highByte= 0xF3` and `lowByte=0xE0`)

using this:

```
void int2bytes(unsigned char dest[2],int val){
             int hByte=0;
             int lByte=0;

             hByte=val&0XFF;
             lByte=val>>8;

             dest[0]= (char)hByte;
             dest[1]= (char)lByte;
            }
```

my question is:

How do I convert(unify) those 2 bytes to one INT equals to "123123"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform the reverse of your function `int2bytes` you simply do this:

```
int val = (lByte << 8) | hByte;
```

Although, I think you have the names of your variables back-to-front. I'd call `val&0xff` the low byte, and `val >> 8` the high byte.

---

You are also mistaken in supposing that you can fit `123123` into 2 bytes. Remember that 2^16 is `65536`.

> I have a function that allows me to separate a int value into 2 bytes (e.g: int "123123" results in E0F3; highByte= 0xF3 and lowByte=0xE0)

Well, E0F3 represented in decimal is equal to 57587. Which is the value you report in the comment you made to my answer.

Now, `123123` represented in hexadecimal is `0x1E0F3` and you need at least three bytes to store that value.

Comment: that returns me the value "57578" instead of "123123". thank you anyway

Comment: My code reverses your code correctly. The problem is that 123123 does not fit into two bytes. "Thank you anyway".

Comment: David Heffernan is correct, 123123 != 0xE0F3.  123123 = 0x1E0F3

Comment: oh! what a mistake by my side, I got really confused about the sizes. I need 3 bytes in fact. 
Now I got the right values thank you David for your time and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(dest[1] << 8) & dest[0]
```

IMHO the hByte and lByte is swapped... And what is more 123123 is not a two byte value. Int is signed, so on two bytes the max value is 32767, but `int` (usually) is 4 bytes.

I might suggest to use a `union` in this case, because you can spare all the arithmetics and you do not need to use explicit conversion at all.

An example code to use union:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::hex;
using std::dec;
using std::endl;

int main() {
   union int2bytes {
       unsigned char byte[sizeof(int)];
       int val;
   };

   int2bytes i;
   // Convert int to byte
   i.val = 123123;
   cout << i.val << " : " << hex << i.val << dec << endl;
   for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(int); ++j)
       cout << "Byte#" << j << " : " << hex << (int)i.byte[j] << dec << endl;

   // Convert byte to int
    i.byte[1]--;
    cout << i.val << " : " << hex << i.val << dec << endl;
}
```

The output:

```
123123 : 1e0f3
Byte#0 : f3
Byte#1 : e0
Byte#2 : 1
Byte#3 : 0
122867 : 1dff3
```

Union can be improved a little bit

```
union int2bytes {
    unsigned char byte[sizeof(int)];
    int val;
    int2bytes (const int2bytes& i = 0) : val(i.val) {};
    int2bytes (int i) : val(i) {};
};
```

Now these work

```
int2bytes i = 123123;
int2bytes j; // j.val == 0
int2bytes k = i;
j = i;
```